# Type attribute not allowing link element to work

Tags: html, css, attributes

When i link a stylesheet with a HTML file and add "type" attribute to it it wont work but it will work if i remove the "type" attribute.

I was try to turn the background black and the text white when it opens in a browser through live server

The Code for html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
<title>My first website</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="author" content="noob"> 
<meta name="description" content="Not My first website ">
<link rel="icon" href="html5.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="css/text">
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Heading 123</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the code for Css file is

```
html {
    font-size: 22px;
}

body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Comment: so what is the actual code? Show the tag with the attribute set.

Comment: Sorry i am new to programming and this website , i have now added both html and css code

Comment: And there you go. You have a typo. It should be `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

The type attribute is swapped

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
```

Comment: https://github.com/gitdagray/html_course/tree/main/02_lesson 
the link code here is working fine

Comment: Okay i found it out seems like i had to write text first and css next in the attribute and i was doing the opposite. Thanks for the help.